# launchDate2 is also a DateTime? type. Why the heck it could be passed to a function that requires a DateTime argument?

Tags: dart

We couldn't pass a `DateTime?` value to a function that requires a `DateTime` argument.
The code below results in an error.

```
class Spacecraft {
  String name;
  DateTime? launchDate;
  
  // Read-only non-final property
  int? get launchYear => launchDate?.year;
  
  // Constructor, with syntactic sugar for assignment to members.
  Spacecraft(this.name, this.launchDate) {
    // Initialization code go here.
  }
  
  // Named constructor that forwards to the default one.
  Spacecraft.unlaunched(String name) : this(name, null);
  
  // Method
  void describe() {
    print('Spacecraft: $name');
  
    if (launchDate != null) {
      int years = DateTime.now().difference(launchDate).inDays ~/ 365;
      print('Launched: $launchYear ($years years ago)');
    } else {
      print('Unlaunched');
    }
  }
}
```

> The argument type 'DateTime?' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'DateTime'.

However, this worked:

```
class Spacecraft {
  String name;
  DateTime? launchDate;
  
  // Read-only non-final property
  int? get launchYear => launchDate?.year;
  
  // Constructor, with syntactic sugar for assignment to members.
  Spacecraft(this.name, this.launchDate) {
    // Initialization code go here.
  }
  
  // Named constructor that forwards to the default one.
  Spacecraft.unlaunched(String name) : this(name, null);
  
  // Method
  void describe() {
    print('Spacecraft: $name');
  
    // Type promotion doesn't work on getters
    var launchDate2 = launchDate;
    if (launchDate2 != null) {
      int years = DateTime.now().difference(launchDate2).inDays ~/ 365;
      print('Launched: $launchYear ($years years ago)');
    } else {
      print('Unlaunched');
    }
  }
}
```

And heck, `launchDate2` is also a `DateTime?` type. Why the heck it could be passed to a function that requires a `DateTime` argument?

Answer (score 0):

`launchDate` refers to a property so it couldn't be promoted or cast. See http://dart.dev/go/non-promo-property and also https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety